# Non-existing field in Mongodb document appears in mongoose findById() result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm somewhat new in what is related to Mongoose and I came to this behaviour I consider as strange. The document returned by Mongoose has fields that are not present in the actual MongoDb document, and seem to be added by Mongoose based on the schema.

I use a schema similar to this (this one is simplified) :

```
const ProfessionalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    product: {
       details: [{
            _id: false,
            id: String, // UUID
            name: String,
            prestations: [{
                _id: false,
                id: String, // UUID
                name: String,
                price: Number,
            }],
        }],
    },
[...]
```

My document as shown in Mongodb with mongo CLI utility doesn't have a product field.

What I don't understand is why the result of Professional.findById().exec() returns a document with a product:{details[]} field. I expect not to have that field in the Mongoose returned result, since it is not present in the original MongoDb document.
The Mongoose documentation found https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html (Schema and Model paragraph) didn't help.

My business logic would require that field not to be present, instead of being forced by the schema. Is this achievable ?

Comment: Try taking a look at the `default` option. You could e.g. default your `product` to `null` and then, in your business logic, handle the "`product` is `null`" case rather than the "`product` field does not exist" case. As for why this is happening, it's because you're dealing with a schema. If the field doesn't exist on the document, it's going to be auto-populated. The whole point of a schema is to ensure consistency of your document structure.

Comment: @B.Fleming, thank you. I'm new to MongoDb, and I must admit that having a schema-less nature of MongoDb combined with Mongoose which is schema-orientated  is quite confusing. Your suggestions seems pretty decent to me. What about posting this comment as an answer ?

Comment: Yeah, taking on both of those at once is definitely confusing. I wasn't 100% sure if this would be a sufficient answer for you, so I submitted it as a comment. I'll be sure to submit a proper answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking a look at the `default` option. You could e.g. default your product to `null` and then, in your business logic, handle the "`product` is `null`" case rather than the "`product` field does not exist" case.

As for why this is happening, it's because you're dealing with a schema. If the field doesn't exist on the document, it's going to be auto-populated. The whole point of a schema is to ensure consistency of your document structure.